ImportError: cannot import name 'cache' from 'RPA.core.webdriver'
I am creating a webscraper and the idea is to use Selenium, Robocorp and VSCode altogether.
I understand that Robocorp already has a file YAML that contains de dependencies of the code, but my doubt is, can I simply PIP INSTALL RPA.core.webdriver?
In my code , there is:
from RPA.core.webdriver import cache, download, start

and then:
def set_webdriver(self, browser="Chrome"):
    options = self.set_chrome_options()
    executable_driver_path = cache(browser)
    if not executable_driver_path:
        executable_driver_path = download(browser)
        self.logger.warning("Using downloaded driver: %s" % executable_driver_path)
    else:
        self.logger.warning("Using cached driver: %s" % executable_driver_path)

    self.driver = start("Chrome", executable_path=str(executable_driver_path), options=options)

Since then the error appears. How can I solve this, with conda.yaml?
# For more details on the format and content:
# https://github.com/robocorp/rcc/blob/master/docs/recipes.md#what-is-in-condayaml
# Tip: Adding a link to the release notes of the packages helps maintenance and security.

channels:
  - conda-forge

dependencies:
  - python=3.10.12                    # https://pyreadiness.org/3.10
  - pip=23.2.1                        # https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news
  - robocorp-truststore=0.8.0         # https://pypi.org/project/robocorp-truststore/
  - nodejs=16.20.2                    # https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md
  - pip:
    - robotframework-browser==17.5.2  # https://github.com/MarketSquare/robotframework-browser/releases
    - rpaframework==27.7.0            # https://rpaframework.org/releasenotes.html

rccPostInstall:
  - rfbrowser init                    # Initialize Playwright

I tried to use a method that uses a dependency, that I have no idea if it's already in the code.
`ImportError: cannot import name 'cache' from 'RPA.core.webdriver`

UPDATE
I managed to install conda into my machine, ran the conda.YAML, created a environment, but I still cannot import this RPA.core. Does it even exists anymore?

Well, it looks like this is a very old architecture used for Selenium. Now, the Chrome webdriver is automatically downloaded and there is no need to specify the path anymore. My current versions accept the following code:
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions
from selenium import webdriver
class CustomSelenium:
    def set_webdriver(self):
    self._driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=self._options)
    print("WebDriver initialized successfully.")

cs = CustomSelenium()


The RPA.core is not meant to be separately used as it is a supporting package for "public" rpaframework packages like the description says in the PyPI

Project description
This package is a set of core functionality and utilities used by RPA Framework. It is not intended to be installed directly, but as a dependency to other projects.

I recommend installing the latest rpaframework==28.6.2 which contains a fix for the latest Chrome webdriver issues.
The cache is not importable from RPA.core.webdriver, but instead of trying to make your code snippet work I ask what you are trying to achieve?

I'm trying to do a python web scraper that utilizes Selenium and RPAframework... The idea is to input a search phrase, the news category, and the number of months i need to receive the news. Finally, I would store the scraped data into a Excel file. But I'm having this issue not because of these functionalities, but because I was pointed to your code to see it as a 'model'. Therefore I am just trying to get the libraries working first so then I could implement the rest.

Yeah, I understood the web scraper target, but I did not understand the need to modify core functionality.

Mika, neither do I haha, but I thought using CustomSelenium would be better in terms of optimization so I chose to use it. Or ExtendedSelenium would be better? Sorry I'm kinda new to RPA
